# PHP: avoid Flood/Spam system by session?

Tags: php, flooding

can I use Session avoid Flood/Spam ? ( spam in form ). I only need avoid use can repeat action as 3,4 action /s .

Comment: Spam as in spams in emails? I can hardly see any relationship between PHP Session and that :)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Why not just use a Captcha system?

Comment: i dont want use Captcha , it feel annoy

Comment: there are ways other than captcha. but it require deep understanding of technology. but still sessions has nothing to do here

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use session mechanism to avoid flood.
Because you can't force a client to keep a session.

You can use session to support CAPTCHA test though.

Answer (score 0):

You could track an IP+UserAgent on the server over a short duration, but you couldn't depend on tracking a cookie (as a user agent like cURL could just disregard saving it) unless a valid cookie matching a session was required to interact with your site.

If the IPs or UserAgents spamming your site/app were constantly changing then there's no sense in even storing them on the server to simulate a cookie.  You'd want to create a CAPTCHA to gate whatever is being spammed.

We'd need more information to be any less general. ;)

Comment: user use cURL can void SEssion on server ? or there has any ways avoid SEssion on server

Comment: Storing a cookie is something the user agent (e.g. browser) has to do consensually.  The request to store a cookie is simply another HTTP Header, and anything (including cURL) can simply ignore it.  If sessions require cookies then anything can avoid a session if you want it to.